# FlyoutAnchor PopulateQueryCommand through clientContext

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, custom-actions

I have a problem.
I want to add Custom action on a Sharepoint Edit form. This must be FlyoutAnchor and i want generate his content dynamically.
I'm adding them throuh ClientContext object model(using C#). This is my code(part omitted):

```
string format = 
        @"<CommandUIExtension xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"">" +
            "<CommandUIDefinitions>" +
                "<CommandUIDefinition Location=\"Ribbon.ListForm.Edit.Actions.Controls._children\">" +
                    "<FlyoutAnchor  Id=\"COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.WithPageComponent.PCNotificationGroup.Dropdown\" Sequence=\"10\" " +
                        " LabelText=\"My layuout\" Alt=\"Sample Flyout\" TemplateAlias=\"o1\" PopulateDynamically=\"true\" PopulateOnlyOnce=\"true\" PopulateQueryCommand=\"COB.PageComponent.Command.PopulateDropDown\" />" +                                
                "</CommandUIDefinition>" +
            "</CommandUIDefinitions>" +
            "<CommandUIHandlers>" +
                "<CommandUIHandler Command=\"Sample.ButtonCommand.Command\" CommandAction=\"javascript:debugger;HelloRibbon(arguments);\" />" +
                "<CommandUIHandler Command=\"COB.PageComponent.Command.PopulateDropDown\" CommandAction=\"javascript:PopulateDropDown.apply(this, arguments);\" />" +
            "</CommandUIHandlers>" +
        "</CommandUIExtension>";
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(TargetUrl);
var site = context.Site;
var populate = site.UserCustomActions.Add();
populate.Title = "PopulateDropDown";
populate.Location = "ScriptLink";
populate.ScriptBlock = // TODO 
populate.Update();
context.Load(list, oList => oList.UserCustomActions);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

but I don't know what to write in TODO string. For simple button action, I can write

`function HelloRibbon(a){alert(a);}`

And it will be call. 
In that article http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/02/ribbon-customizations-dropdown-controls.html i founded sample code, in "2. JavaScript page component" section there is code that generate menu items dynamically. But i don't know how i must adapt this code to ClientContext object model.
Thanks for help.

Comment: http://patrickboom.wordpress.com/tag/pagecomponent/ There I find the same example. But there author register population function as a page component. I'm try to do this. But when my page loaded i see error in javascript console "Uncaught ReferenceError: CUI is not defined ". It is on call `COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.registerClass(\'COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent\', CUI.Page.PageComponent);`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved in that thread

[Registering pageComponent using ClientObjectModel](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58110/registering-pagecomponent-using-clientobjectmodel)

this code work

```
        "ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded ( function () {" +
        "COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.registerClass(\'COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent\', CUI.Page.PageComponent);" +
        "COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.instance = new COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent();" +
        "COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.initialize()"" }, \"CUI.js\" );";
```