# Registering pageComponent using ClientObjectModel

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, custom-actions

is there any ways to register PageComponent using client object model?
I want to add custom action on the edit form with dynamically populating FlyoutAnchor. But when page has been loaded i recieve following error "Uncaught ReferenceError: CUI is not defined ".
I think this is because my page component was not loaded.
I'm trying to do this by this code(C#):

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(TargetUrl);
var site = context.Site;
var populate = site.UserCustomActions.Add();
populate.Title = "PopulateDropDown";
populate.Location = "ScriptLink";
populate.ScriptBlock = 
        "Type.registerNamespace(\'COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent\');" +
        "COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent = function () {" +
             "COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.initializeBase(this);" +
        "};" + 
        "COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.initialize = function () {" +
             "ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Function.createDelegate(null,   COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.initializePageComponent), \'SP.Ribbon.js\');" +
         "};" +
         "COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.initializePageComponent = function() {" +
             "var ribbonPageManager = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance();" +
             "if (null !== ribbonPageManager) {" +
                 "ribbonPageManager.addPageComponent(COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.instance);" +
             "}" +
         "};" +
         "COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.prototype = {" +
             "init: function () { }," +

         // some code there

         "};" +

        "function PopulateDropDown(commandId, properties, sequence){" +
            "var sb = new Sys.StringBuilder();" +
            "sb.append(\"<Menu Id=\'Sample.account.form.Menu\'>\");" +
            "sb.append(\"<MenuSection Id=\'Sample.account.form.MenuSection\' Title=\'Menu Section Title\' Sequence=\'15\'>\");" +
            "sb.append(\"<Controls Id=\'Sample.account.form.MenuSection.Controls\'>\");" +
            "sb.append(\"<Button Id=\'Sample.account.form.Controls.Button.FirstButton\' Command=\'Sample.ButtonCommand.Command\' LabelText=\'First Button\' ToolTipTitle=\'First Button\' ToolTipDescription=\'The first button\' TemplateAlias=\'o2\' Sequence=\'20\' />\");" +
        "   sb.append(\"</Controls>\");" +
           "sb.append(\"</MenuSection>\");" +
           "sb.append(\"</Menu>\");" +
           "CommandProperties.PopulationXML = sb.toString();return true;" +
        "};"  +
  "COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.registerClass(\'COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent\', CUI.Page.PageComponent);" +
        "COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.instance = new COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent();" +
        "NotifyScriptLoadedAndExecuteWaitingJobs(\'COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.js\');";

        populate.Update();
        context.Load(site, oList => oList.UserCustomActions);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be added in the end of script. It's work.

```
            "ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded ( function () {" +
            "COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.registerClass(\'COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent\', CUI.Page.PageComponent);" +
            "COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.instance = new COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent();" +
            "COB.SharePoint.Ribbon.PageComponent.initialize()"" }, \"CUI.js\" );";
```